# Заполнить id последовательными числами

Tags: sql, postgresql

Какой командой можно заполнить `id` от `0` до `N` последовательными числами?

Comment: Уточните, вам надо вставить новые значения в таблицу или изменить уже существующие записи ?

Comment: Вставить новые значения в таблицу

Comment: Тогда insert select ... как в принятом ответе. А мне по тексту вопроса показалось, что у вас уже есть какие то данные и надо в них проставить порядковые номера в id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Задачи и решения - Генерация числовой последовательности](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_number_sequence_generation/page2.html):

```
SELECT generate_series(1,100) AS num
```